# How to assign a new permission to a running EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, roles, amazon-iam

I am performing some tests with EC2, and I want to limit the permissions to an already running instance, to only describe other instances (for example, if it requests the creation of a new one, that request should be denied).

I created an IAM Role with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This theoretically should prevent me from creating new instances when I am logged on the already running instance, but it does not (I am using `boto` library for the test, with `ec2.run_instances()`).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"This theoretically should prevent me from creating new instances when I am logged on the already running instance."*  Only if you are using that instance's role credentials.  If you are using *other* credentials, you can do anything those credentials allow.  Can you clarify a bit, exactly what you're doing?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you spotted the exact problem :) thank. Could you please write this in an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I don't want to mischaracterize the problem... the issue is you assumed instance role policy impacted all API requests from the instance regardless of credentials? Or you had stored some IAM credentials on the instance and they were being used without you realizing it?

Comment: I have stored some credentials somewhere and forgot about them, so the boto lib was still using those credentials, with which you basically have all the rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy attached to an IAM Instance Role only affects requests made using the instance role credentials.  It doesn't have any impact on requests made using other credentials (such as the access key id and secret of an IAM user), even though the requests come from code running on the instance.

In the case, here, where unexpected privileges are available, the likely explanation is that another set of credentials is stored on the instance, and the code is using those without the developer realizing it.

This is perhaps a good illustration of one reason why it's considered a best practice to *only* use role credentials in code running on EC2, and not store other credentials on the instance.